# How to decouple nodes and cores with MPI?

Tags: python, parallel-processing, multiprocessing, mpi, cluster-computing

I have code currently using multiprocessing with `joblib` to distribute computations from a loop over multiple cores within one cluster node, like so:

```py
from joblib import Parallel, delayed
def function():
    return Parallel(n_jobs=28)(delayed(computation)() for _ in range(n_iter))
save(function()) # save results to some file
...
```

I am limited to 28 cores on a cluster/node but I'd like to run the above task 4 times.  This might strain the multiprocessing load and hinder performance. I've looked into `mpi4py` which uses the MPI standard to concurrently run code on multiple nodes.

From what I've learned, I want my code, `script.py` to follow this pattern:

```py
from mpi4py import MPI
comm = MPI.COMM_WORLD
my_rank = comm.Get_rank() # number assigned to a node
# below, num_proc would be 5: node 0 receives data,
# and nodes 1-4 doing the work
num_proc = comm.Get_size() 

if my_rank != 0:
    comm.send(function(), dest=0)
else:
    for proc_id in range(1, num_proc):
        result = comm.recv(source=proc_id)
        save(result)
```

The script to submit a job with MPI using [TORQUE](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/TORQUE) has the general pattern:

```bash
#PBS -l nodes=5:ppn=28 # ppn is parts per node, or number of cores
...
mpirun -np $np python script.py
```

But from what I've seen<sup>1</sup>, `$np` here should be `nodes` * `ppn`.  However, in the loop in `script.py` above, I want num_proc to correspond to the number of nodes, and `n_jobs` in `function`'s `Parallel` call to correspond to `ppn`.

How do I tell MPI to 'decouple' nodes and cores?  If I submit `mpirun -np 5 python script.py`, is `joblib` distributing my computation across 28 cores per node, and `mpi4py` distributing this function to 4 nodes?

I know there are various binding options with `mpirun` but based on [the docs](https://www.open-mpi.org/doc/v1.8/man1/mpirun.1.php) am not sure which one is appropriate.

**References** 
<sup>1</sup> see 'submitting a job' in [this cluster user guide](https://www.sdsc.edu/support/user_guides/tscc.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If what I understood is correct, you need to launch one mpi process per node in 5 nodes and each process should be able to use all cores (28) with python multiprocessing.

Using this mapping should be sufficient:

```
mpirun -np $np --map-by ppr:1:node #np is 5
```

MPI will launch a process per node. Inside the node, python can use all the available cores.

Comment: This does the trick. I noticed however, that when I log the number of cores on each node (using joblib's `cpu_count()`), the number of ppn is incorrect on one of the nodes.  Why might that be?